# Custom exposed filter to select expired nodes

Tags: views

In my Drupal 7 website I have a content type called "offer" that has a date field called "deadline".

When the current date is greater than deadline, then the offer is expired.

I would like to make a form with Views where I can put a radio button like this:
Expired: yes   no

Is it possible to do that?

I know that a solution could be to make a new field, to call that "expired", and finally to make a cron to set the value on yes when the node deadline is lesser than the current date.
I was looking for something easier...

I made some steps forward.
The solution should be using the grouped filters, but it doesn't allow me to chose the relative date:

[image: screenshot filter settings]

Comment: Hi, 
If you need help (in italian..) send me an email to benedetta.sferrella@gmail.com ^^

Answer (score 0):

What about running a cron task that sets the status of offers to  unpublished once the expiry date has passed.

Then the view can simply filter on whether or not the node is published.

If you don't want to go down that route then alternatively create a filter based on date and then with a little jQuery hide that and add some radios. Then when the radio is changed set the date filter to the appropriate value and submit the form.

Comment: thanks, but maybe you did not read entirely my question... ;)

Comment: I've added an alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: I was looking for something more "drupal way", but thanks.